# How to put array of string into another array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to save my json data from api to array of dictionaries. After that I save the subcategory "name" into an array according to each subcategories so that I can populate it in expanding tableview respectively.  For that I have to create  array of array in which I can store the category wise data in array to display it. Here I have not used Any Class model. So By creating globally How can i do it.

**Codes:**

```
           do {
            let json1 = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,  
             options: NSJSONReadingOptions())

            self.AllData = json1.valueForKey("name") as! Array<String>
            print(self.AllData)


            print("Number of menu = \(json1.count)")

            for var i in 0..<json1.count {
              print(" \n \(i+1) row menu \n")


                if let subs = json1[i]["subcategory"] as? [[String: 
                  AnyObject]] {

                    print("\(subs.count) subcategories")
                    var SUBCAT : [String] = []

                    for sub in subs {

                        if let name = sub["name"] as? String {
                            print("subcategory name= \t \(name)")
                            SUBCAT.append(name)
                            print(SUBCAT.count)
                         }
                    print("Number of subcategory= \(subs.count)")
                    print("SubValue : \(SUBCAT)")
                   }// end for
                }//end if
            }//close json1.count loop
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }



        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.MenuTableView.reloadData()
```

Here in this line `print("SubValue : \(SUBCAT)")` it displays all data subcategory wise. But here after how can I save it into another array so that i can pass all the array data to table view to display it You can see the data.

**Check my data below**

> SubValue : ["ALL HAM IS TURKEY PRODUCT", "Margherita Pizza", "Chicken
>           Tikka Pizza", "Tropical Pizza", "Pepperoni Pizza", "Apollo Pizza", "Doner 
>         Pizza", "Kiev Pizza", "Vegetarian Supreme Pizza", "Marinara Pizza", "Hot and 
>         Spicy Pizza", "Mexicano Devil Pizza", "Asian Style Pizza", "NEW Any Curry
>         Pizza", "NEW Flaming Ricki Pizza", "Meat Bonanza Pizza", "Flames Full House 
>         Pizza", "BBQ Pizza", "Calazone", "THE HUGE ONE (16 inch)", "Garlic Bread", 
>         "Garlic Bread and Cheese", "Garlic Bread Special"]

This is the first subcategory data . Likewise another subcategory data is there. I need help.

Comment: Please improve your formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var values = ["Value1", "Value2"]
let moreValues = ["Value3", "Value4"]

values.appendContentsOf(moreValues)
```

Comment: I am asking how to create array of array

Comment: You mean multi dimensional array? Something like [ ["Value 1", "Value 2"], ["Value3"], ["Value4"] ]

Comment: @PRADIPKUMAR That's exactly what Diogo described to you in his comment: `[ ["Value 1", "Value 2"], ["Value3"], ["Value4"] ]`, it's an array of arrays.

Comment: If it responds to your question please mark it as answer

Comment: The above code is an single dimension array.@DiogoAntunes

Answer (score 0):

You may use this template code:

```
var data = [[String]]()
let subData1: [String] = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
let subData2: [String] = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
data.append(subData1)
data.append(subData2)
```